Invitation for Unregistered Users to Opt-In to Research
Starting today, logged-out users on Stack Overflow will see a banner with a survey to join our research panel. This simply means opting in to be contacted to participate in future research opportunities the company conducts. Unregistered users make up a significant portion of the Stack Overflow community, and we want to better understand their unique experiences. To ensure that this group of users is included in future research efforts, the banner will only be shown to those who are not logged in.
The survey linked from the banner is specifically intended for users who browse the site but have never created an account. After answering a few questions about their experience on Stack Overflow, they may receive occasional invitations to participate in research, depending on the relevance of the research topic to their experience. Those who sign up can also opt-out at any time by clicking the unsubscribe link included in all our research invitation emails.
While we are currently focusing on unregistered users, you can always let us know if you are interested in participating in the future. If you already have an account on Stack Overflow, you can opt into receiving research opportunities in your email settings.
We plan on having this survey banner run for approximately two weeks and it is dismissible. If we decide to extend the timeline of the banner being live, we’ll update this post to let you know.
Here's a screenshot of the banner so you can see what it looks like.

Feel free to let us know if you have any questions.

What kind of questions are you asking?

Is there any rationale behind focusing on unregistered users, other than the portion? From my experience, most unregistered users are one-time spammer account. I am not sure it worths the time and effort on this approach.

Starting a new research project for unregistered users feels like another confirmation that SE stopped caring about existing users and longterm viability and instead chases growth metrics such as new user signups or time spent on SE (=ad sales). Which feels about as wise as firing all staff to improve the quarterly results. Even if that research yields significant findings, do you have capacity to address them while discussions drowns in spam, SG has tons of issues, etc? Not that I expect an answer to that as this was probably directed by upper mgmt and Rosie is just the bearer of dumb news...

I feel like the above two comments are reading this too negatively. I think the rationale in the first paragraph of the post makes sense.

@l4mpi well maybe... I mean the site is well and filled nowadays, people using the site as intended have far less reason to sign up. You go to Google/Bing/etc., you search, you find an answer, you click, you "adopt", you leave. I can see how unregistered users are of special interest.

@ray @starball’s comment is correct. The first paragraph is the rationale of this current survey. Since unregistered users are unable to sign up for research opportunities through their account's email settings (as they don't have an account yet), we wanted a way to provide them with opportunities to talk with the Stack Overflow team. Our team is looking to better understand their motivations for coming to the site and why they haven’t taken the step of setting up an account. 1/2

Separately, we're always interested in chatting with existing users as well, and existing users can opt into receiving research opportunities in their email settings.2/2

I sometimes browse SO in incognito, and I saw this banner and clicked on it. It immediately asked me to "sign up" (to a different thing), so I closed it. So, if I (someone with an actual account) thought it was too much of a hassle, imagine how tedious it might look to someone who didn't bother to create an account in the first place. Btw, I'm not saying that I'm against this research effort; I'm just giving my perspective. At least consider moving the sign-up to the end of the survey, or remove the name/last name thing

Btw, the banner does not make it obvious that it is aimed at unregistered users (I can't imagine I'm the only one that regularly googles errors in incognito, so I don't clutter my browser history)
